# R Loop through Columns

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, cap

How to loop through columns in a Data Frame and cap the values at 97.5th percentile of that column?

Eg. if one particular column has values 1 to 100 filled in it, the value >97.5, i.e 98, 99 and 100 should all be given 97.5.

Please see, I want to do this for columns 4 to last in the data frame.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you give example of data ? Also, read more about positing questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in one line in base R

```
#set up the data
df <- data.frame(a = sample(100,replace=TRUE), 
                 b = sample(100,replace=TRUE),
                 c = sample(100,replace=TRUE))

df2 <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) pmin(x, quantile(x, 0.975))))
```

To just modify columns 4 to 10 (for example) of your dataframe, you could do

```
data[,4:10] <- as.data.frame(lapply(data[,4:10], function(x) pmin(x, quantile(x, 0.975))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a minimal example of what you are trying to do. Here I'm modifying the last 2 columns:

```
set.seed(2)

library(data.table)
df <- data.table(a = runif(10, 90, 100), 
                 b = runif(10, 95, 105),
                 c = runif(10, 90, 100))

df[,c('b','c') := lapply(.SD, function(x) pmin(x, quantile(x, 0.975))), .SDcols = c('b','c')]

print(df)

           a         b        c
 1: 91.82174 103.40371 99.49889
 2: 93.60763 104.45268 91.01073
 3: 99.03800  95.44965 92.56751
 4: 93.94048 102.58383 98.95147
 5: 97.79881  97.96888 93.87944
 6: 92.84159 101.51054 97.94285
 7: 98.53721  95.84990 93.49397
 8: 91.72242 104.68683 91.38744
 9: 90.79264  95.13625 96.50509
10: 92.92065 100.38869 95.44004
```

Comment: Or in base R : `DF[] <- lapply(DF,function(x)ifelse(x>97.5,97.5, x))`

Comment: Why is this downvoted ?

Comment: @ManishSaraswat Probably because the OP is asking about quantiles of the data, rather than the values.

Comment: @AndrewGustar Thanks a lot. This excitement of answering questions drives me crazy sometimes. I'll be careful from now.

Comment: @ManishSaraswat I know the feeling - we've all done it!

Answer (score 1):

Using the data that @ManishSaraswat set up, I believe you want something like this,

```
df <- data.frame(a = runif(10, 90, 100), 
                 b = runif(10, 95, 105),
                 c = runif(10, 90, 100))
apply(df, 2, function(x){
  quant <- quantile(x, 0.975)
  ifelse(x > quant, quant, x)
})
```

I hope this helps!